# A part of the webview content cannot be displayed when zoom factor > 5

Tags: c#, windows, tablet

I have a scrollviewer which contains a webview as content.When I zoom in(zoom factor > 5), a part of content can not be displayed.So Is this a bug?
[screen capture]
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpqsor36cm6txbo/zoom_problem.xlsx

**XAML File**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="svMain" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="0.7" MaxZoomFactor="10.0" Background="White" ViewChanged="svMain_ViewChanged" >
        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <WebView Name="webview1" Source="http://www.yahoo.co.jp" Height="400" Width="400"  

Grid.Column="1"></WebView>
            <TextBlock Name="txtZoom" Margin="10,93,710,616" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

**CS File**

```
namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void svMain_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtZoom.Text = svMain.ZoomFactor.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```